# How to escape a colon inside a datetime value in a JSON string

Tags: java, json, datetime

I need to instantiate a JSONObject with a string that I receive from an external source. The string contains a datetime value, which in turn contains a colon. 
When I try to create an instance of the JSONObject, I get an error, it looks like JSON does not like the colon in the middle of the date time value.

Here is a code snippet:

```
@Test
public void testGetDate()
{
    String jsonStr = "{\"sDate\":2013-06-15T09:30:09+0000}";
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        System.out.println(jsonObject.get("sDate"));

    } catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 23 [character 24 line 1]
```

Has anyone encountered this ? Is there some way to escape the colon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you surround your date/time object in double quotes, it should accept it.

This should work:

```
String jsonStr = "{\"sDate\":\"2013-06-15T09:30:09+0000\"}";
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are [required to be quoted in JSON](http://json.org/):

```
string
  ""
  " chars "
```

Your snippet is invalid, which is why the exception is thrown. You must surround the string value with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The more interesting issue is for cases where the string is unknown.  In case the format is known then it's reasonably easy to fix.  Added as a utility to org.json [here](https://github.com/amirgur1/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONDateUtils.java#L22).