# Deserialize LocalDateTime when it contains zone information

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson, localdate

I have received a timestamp from a server and I want to deserialize it to a `LocalDateTime` instance.

The timestamp I received has time zone information and its similar to this string

```
2022-03-24T22:44:03.241082Z[Etc/UTC]
```

When I try to deserialize it using `Gson` I get the following exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-03-24T22' could not be parsed at index 13

    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:477)
    at myapp.libraries.serialization.decoders.LocalDateTimeDecoder.deserialize(LocalDateTimeDecoder.kt:15)
    at myapp.libraries.serialization.decoders.LocalDateTimeDecoder.deserialize(LocalDateTimeDecoder.kt:13)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
    at myapp.libraries.serialization.SerializationSpec.It must deserialize LocalDateTime(SerializationSpec.kt:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

My deserialization code is

```
class LocalDateTimeDecoder : JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): LocalDateTime {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(json?.asJsonPrimitive?.asString)
    }
}
```

How can I deserialize this?

Comment: Did you try deserialising it to a `ZonedDateTime` then calling `toLocalDateTime`?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I have tried `ZonedDateTime.parse(timestamp)` and it threw a similar exception

Comment: OK next question - why do you have both the `Z` and the part inside `[]`?  Stating the timezone twice might be the problem.  I'm guessing here - I didn't try it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I don't really know the reason for that. This is the response I got back from a server

Comment: The error message says the received text is `2022-03-24T22`, not `2022-03-24T22:44:03.241082Z[Etc/UTC]`. Seems the value is truncated somewhere else. Re-check your assumptions.

Comment: I'm wondering if you have to do something special to escape the `:` from GSON, since `:` has special meaning in JSON.  Just guessing.

Comment: ISO 8601 specifies that a time can be just the hour value, so `2022-03-24T22` is a valid ISO 8601 value, but [`LocalDateTime.parse(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) requires that minute is present too, which means you need a custom `DateTimeFormatter` when parsing that as 22:00 hours. That is, assuming the problem is not a truncation issue, but that text is actually what is received.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I haven't done anything to truncate it. I printed the value of `json?.asJsonPrimitive?.asString` and it seems that it's truncated at this point. I also tried the `toString` method and got the same result.

Comment: @InvisibleCoder Have you tried looking at the full JSON received? To be sure what you're actually working with.

Comment: @Andreas I don't think providing the full JSON here is useful. It seems that  as soon as I call `gson.fromJson()` the value gets truncated. I have tried using the `LocalDateTimeDecoder` and it is able to deserlalize the value `2022-03-24T22:44:03.241082Z[Etc/UTC]`

Comment: That would support my hypothesis that you need to do something in the JSON to escape the colon.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem any idea how I can escape it?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/17050807

Comment: @InvisibleCoder JSON doesn't support date/time literals, so the value must be a string literal, i.e. quoted, which means that colons have no special meaning. I don't see how Gson can have trouble parsing the JSON text, unless it's invalid, i.e. the `2022-03-24T22:44:03.241082Z[Etc/UTC]` value is unquoted, in which case the server generating the JSON must be fixed to generate *valid* JSON. --- I didn't ask for us to see the full JSON text, just for you to look at it, but it would be very useful if you could show us the part of the *raw* JSON text surrounding where this value occurs.

Comment: @Andreas the string is in double quotes inside the Json

Comment: And you're still not going to show us. Ok: "[How to create a Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: @InvisibleCoder It will be much easier to answer the question if you can update the question with actual json snippet and code for deserializing it.